# Lighttpd server fastcgi PHP 404 not found

Tags: php, wordpress, fastcgi, lighttpd

thats my nightmare I'm working on for 2days..
My wordpress pages are not working, I'm gettin "404 not found"
also when I try to restart lighttpd server I'm getting this

**"(plugin.c.131) Cannot load plugin mod_fastcgi more than once, please fix your config (we may not accept such configs in future releases"**

**`this is my lighttpd.conf file.`**

```
server.modules = (
        "mod_access",
        "mod_alias",
        "mod_compress",
        "mod_redirect",
        "mod_rewrite",
        "mod_accesslog",
        "mod_fastcgi",
)
server.tag = "Private Server"
server.max-fds = 8192
server.max-connections = 4096
server.document-root        = "/var/www"
server.upload-dirs          = ( "/var/cache/lighttpd/uploads" )
server.errorlog             = "/var/log/lighttpd/error.log"
accesslog.filename      = "/var/log/lighttpd/access.log"
server.pid-file             = "/var/run/lighttpd.pid"
server.username             = "www-data"
server.groupname            = "www-data"
server.port                 = 80

index-file.names            = ( "index.php", "index.html", "index.lighttpd.html" )
url.access-deny             = ( "~", ".inc" )
static-file.exclude-extensions = ( ".scgi", ".php", ".pl", ".fcgi" )

compress.cache-dir          = "/var/cache/lighttpd/compress/"
compress.filetype           = ( "application/javascript", "application/x-javascript", "text/x-js", "text/css", "text/xml", "text/javascript", "text/html", "text/plain"$
# default listening port for IPv6 falls back to the IPv4 port
include_shell "/usr/share/lighttpd/use-ipv6.pl " + server.port
include_shell "/usr/share/lighttpd/create-mime.assign.pl"
include_shell "/usr/share/lighttpd/include-conf-enabled.pl"
include "test.com.conf"
fastcgi.server = ( ".php" => ((
                     "bin-path" => "/usr/bin/php5-cgi",
                     "socket" => "/var/run/lighttpd/php-fastcgi.socket",
                "max-procs" => 5,
                "bin-environment" => (
                        "PHP_FCGI_CHILDREN" => "40",
                        "PHP_FCGI_MAX_REQUESTS" => "10000"
                ),
                "bin-copy-environment" => (
                        "PATH", "SHELL", "USER"
                ),
                "broken-scriptfilename" => "enable"
                 )))
```

Answer (score 3):

if you have enabled fastcgi. fastcgi.conf file already adds fastcgi module

`server.modules += ( "mod_fastcgi" )`

you don't need to add it to `lighttpd.conf`

Comment: yorum yapda ben onlarıda like'layım

Answer (score 0):

You can not load modules twice.

Use the following command to find where you have loaded your module twice.

```
$ grep -i -r -n -e "mod_fastcgi" /etc/lighttpd (where you store your config files)
```

Answer (score 0):

Module loaded twice isn't great (and should be fixed), but it doesn't trigger your current issue.

To be able to understand the issue, you have to enable more logs in lighttpd configuration:

`debug.log-request-handling  = "enable"`

Will add a lot of useful things in the `/var/log/lighttpd/error.log`.

So :

- add the new parameter in configuration
- restart lighttpd
- `tail -f /var/log/lighttpd/error.log`
- load your page and look at the output of `tail`

Most probably lighttpd is looking for your file in the wrong place, and with all the rewrites and so on you'll be able to find out where you're mistaken.